# FirebaseCore - Lexical or Preprocessor issue - 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I was trying to add the firebase SDK to my react-native project and I keep running into this issue when building the app in Xcode. I've tried lots of different version checks on cocoapods and GoogleUtilities but I cannot get rid of this error.

Xcode Version: 11.3

Cocoapods Version: 1.8.4

Here's the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'fitness' do
  pod 'ExpoKit',
    :git => "http://github.com/expo/expo.git",
    :tag => "ios/2.11.5",
    :subspecs => [
      "Core"
    ],
    :inhibit_warnings => true

  # Install unimodules
  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
  use_unimodules!(
    modules_paths: ['../node_modules'],
    exclude: [
      'expo-bluetooth',
      'expo-in-app-purchases',
      'expo-payments-stripe',
    ],
  )

  pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "ART",
      "RCTActionSheet",
      "RCTAnimation",
      "RCTCameraRoll",
      "RCTGeolocation",
      "RCTImage",
      "RCTNetwork",
      "RCTText",
      "RCTVibration",
      "RCTWebSocket",
      "DevSupport",
      "CxxBridge"
    ]
  pod 'yoga',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'DoubleConversion',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'Folly',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'glog',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true

  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.3.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 6.3.0'
```

And the Podfile.lock:

```
  - Amplitude-iOS (3.14.1)
  - Analytics (3.7.0)
  - AppAuth (0.95.1)
  - Bolts (1.9.0):
    - Bolts/AppLinks (= 1.9.0)
    - Bolts/Tasks (= 1.9.0)
  - Bolts/AppLinks (1.9.0):
    - Bolts/Tasks
  - Bolts/Tasks (1.9.0)
  - boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (= 0.0.3)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.3)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (0.0.3):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.3)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (0.0.3)
  - Branch (0.24.2):
    - Branch/Core (= 0.24.2)
  - Branch/Core (0.24.2)
  - CocoaLumberjack (3.2.1):
    - CocoaLumberjack/Default (= 3.2.1)
    - CocoaLumberjack/Extensions (= 3.2.1)
  - CocoaLumberjack/Default (3.2.1)
  - CocoaLumberjack/Extensions (3.2.1):
    - CocoaLumberjack/Default
  - Crashlytics (3.14.0):
    - Fabric (~> 1.10.2)
  - DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
  - EXAdsAdMob (5.0.1):
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
    - UMCore
  - EXAdsFacebook (5.0.1):
    - FBAudienceNetwork
    - UMCore
  - EXAmplitude (5.0.1):
    - Amplitude-iOS
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
  - EXAppAuth (5.0.1):
    - AppAuth
    - UMCore
  - EXAppLoaderProvider (5.0.1)
  - EXAV (5.0.2):
    - UMCore
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - EXBackgroundFetch (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMTaskManagerInterface
  - EXBarCodeScanner (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMImageLoaderInterface
  - EXBlur (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXBrightness (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXCalendar (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - EXCamera (5.0.1):
    - UMBarCodeScannerInterface
    - UMCore
    - UMFaceDetectorInterface
    - UMFileSystemInterface
    - UMImageLoaderInterface
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - EXConstants (5.0.1):
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
  - EXContacts (5.0.2):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - EXCrypto (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXDocumentPicker (5.0.2):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXFacebook (5.0.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
  - EXFaceDetector (5.0.1):
    - GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector (~> 1.1.0)
    - GoogleMobileVision/MVDataOutput (~> 1.1.0)
    - UMCore
    - UMFaceDetectorInterface
  - EXFileSystem (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXFont (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFontInterface
  - EXGL (5.0.1):
    - EXGL-CPP
    - UMCameraInterface
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXGL-CPP (5.0.1):
    - EXGL-CPP/UEXGL (= 5.0.1)
  - EXGL-CPP/UEXGL (5.0.1)
  - EXGoogleSignIn (5.0.1):
    - GoogleSignIn (~> 4.4)
    - UMCore
  - EXHaptics (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXImageManipulator (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
    - UMImageLoaderInterface
  - EXImagePicker (5.0.2):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXKeepAwake (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXLinearGradient (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXLocalAuthentication (5.0.1):
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
  - EXLocalization (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXLocation (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMPermissionsInterface
    - UMTaskManagerInterface
  - EXMailComposer (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXMediaLibrary (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - EXPermissions (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - ExpoKit/Core (33.0.0):
    - Amplitude-iOS (~> 3.8)
    - Analytics (~> 3.5)
    - AppAuth (~> 0.4)
    - Branch (~> 0.24.2)
    - CocoaLumberjack (~> 3.2.1)
    - Crashlytics (~> 3.8)
    - Fabric (~> 1.6)
    - FBAudienceNetwork (= 5.1.1)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (= 4.40.0)
    - FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.40.0)
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (~> 2.1.0)
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.22.0)
    - GoogleMaps (~> 2.5.0)
    - GoogleSignIn (~> 4.1)
    - JKBigInteger2 (= 0.0.5)
    - lottie-ios (~> 2.5.0)
    - React
    - UMCameraInterface
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
    - UMPermissionsInterface
    - UMReactNativeAdapter
    - UMSensorsInterface
  - EXPrint (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXRandom (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXSecureStore (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
  - EXSegment (5.0.1):
    - Analytics (~> 3.5)
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
  - EXSensors (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMSensorsInterface
  - EXSharing (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXSMS (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMPermissionsInterface
  - EXSpeech (5.0.2):
    - UMCore
  - EXSQLite (5.0.1):
    - UMCore
    - UMFileSystemInterface
  - EXTaskManager (5.0.1):
    - EXAppLoaderProvider
    - UMConstantsInterface
    - UMCore
    - UMTaskManagerInterface
  - EXWebBrowser (5.0.3):
    - UMCore
  - Fabric (1.10.2)
  - FBAudienceNetwork (5.1.1)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (4.40.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (4.40.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
  - Firebase/Auth (6.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.1.2)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.3.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.0.3)
  - Firebase/Firestore (6.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (~> 1.4.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (6.1.2):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.0.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.0)
  - FirebaseFirestore (1.4.2):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - FirebaseFirestore/abseil-cpp (= 1.4.2)
    - "gRPC-C++ (= 0.0.9)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.20)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseFirestore/abseil-cpp (1.4.2):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - "gRPC-C++ (= 0.0.9)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.20)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - Folly (2018.10.22.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - DoubleConversion
    - glog
  - glog (0.3.5)
  - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (2.1.0):
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Clustering (= 2.1.0)
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Geometry (= 2.1.0)
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Heatmap (= 2.1.0)
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/QuadTree (= 2.1.0)
    - GoogleMaps
  - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Clustering (2.1.0):
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/QuadTree
    - GoogleMaps
  - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Geometry (2.1.0):
    - GoogleMaps
  - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Heatmap (2.1.0):
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/QuadTree
    - GoogleMaps
  - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/QuadTree (2.1.0):
    - GoogleMaps
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.22.0)
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleMaps (2.5.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 2.5.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (2.5.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (2.5.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GoogleMobileVision/Detector (1.1.0):
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.3)
  - GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector (1.1.0):
    - GoogleMobileVision/Detector
  - GoogleMobileVision/MVDataOutput (1.1.0):
    - GoogleMobileVision/Detector
  - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSignIn (4.4.0):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.2.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.2.2)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.2.2)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.2.2)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.2.2)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.2.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.4.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.4.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.4.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - "gRPC-C++ (0.0.9)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 0.0.9)"
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 0.0.9)"
  - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (0.0.9)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 0.0.9)"
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.21.0)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - "gRPC-C++/Interface (0.0.9)"
  - gRPC-Core (1.21.0):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.21.0)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.21.0)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.21.0):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC (= 0.0.3)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.21.0)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.21.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.3.0)
  - JKBigInteger2 (0.0.5)
  - leveldb-library (1.22)
  - lottie-ios (2.5.3)
  - nanopb (0.3.9011):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.9011)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.9011)
  - Protobuf (3.11.2)
  - React (0.59.8):
    - React/Core (= 0.59.8)
  - React/ART (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/Core (0.59.8):
    - yoga (= 0.59.8.React)
  - React/CxxBridge (0.59.8):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - React/Core
    - React/cxxreact
    - React/jsiexecutor
  - React/cxxreact (0.59.8):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React/jsinspector
  - React/DevSupport (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTWebSocket
  - React/fishhook (0.59.8)
  - React/jsi (0.59.8):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
  - React/jsiexecutor (0.59.8):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React/cxxreact
    - React/jsi
  - React/jsinspector (0.59.8)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTAnimation (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTBlob (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTCameraRoll (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTImage
  - React/RCTGeolocation (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTImage (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTNetwork
  - React/RCTNetwork (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTText (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTVibration (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTWebSocket (0.59.8):
    - React/Core
    - React/fishhook
    - React/RCTBlob
  - UMBarCodeScannerInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMCameraInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMConstantsInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMCore (2.0.1)
  - UMFaceDetectorInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMFileSystemInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMFontInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMImageLoaderInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMPermissionsInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMReactNativeAdapter (2.0.1):
    - React
    - UMCore
    - UMFontInterface
  - UMSensorsInterface (2.0.1)
  - UMTaskManagerInterface (2.0.1)
  - yoga (0.59.8.React)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
  - EXAdsAdMob (from `../node_modules/expo-ads-admob/ios`)
  - EXAdsFacebook (from `../node_modules/expo-ads-facebook/ios`)
  - EXAmplitude (from `../node_modules/expo-analytics-amplitude/ios`)
  - EXAppAuth (from `../node_modules/expo-app-auth/ios`)
  - EXAppLoaderProvider (from `../node_modules/expo-app-loader-provider/ios`)
  - EXAV (from `../node_modules/expo-av/ios`)
  - EXBackgroundFetch (from `../node_modules/expo-background-fetch/ios`)
  - EXBarCodeScanner (from `../node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner/ios`)
  - EXBlur (from `../node_modules/expo-blur/ios`)
  - EXBrightness (from `../node_modules/expo-brightness/ios`)
  - EXCalendar (from `../node_modules/expo-calendar/ios`)
  - EXCamera (from `../node_modules/expo-camera/ios`)
  - EXConstants (from `../node_modules/expo-constants/ios`)
  - EXContacts (from `../node_modules/expo-contacts/ios`)
  - EXCrypto (from `../node_modules/expo-crypto/ios`)
  - EXDocumentPicker (from `../node_modules/expo-document-picker/ios`)
  - EXFacebook (from `../node_modules/expo-facebook/ios`)
  - EXFaceDetector (from `../node_modules/expo-face-detector/ios`)
  - EXFileSystem (from `../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios`)
  - EXFont (from `../node_modules/expo-font/ios`)
  - EXGL (from `../node_modules/expo-gl/ios`)
  - EXGL-CPP (from `../node_modules/expo-gl-cpp/cpp`)
  - EXGoogleSignIn (from `../node_modules/expo-google-sign-in/ios`)
  - EXHaptics (from `../node_modules/expo-haptics/ios`)
  - EXImageManipulator (from `../node_modules/expo-image-manipulator/ios`)
  - EXImagePicker (from `../node_modules/expo-image-picker/ios`)
  - EXKeepAwake (from `../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios`)
  - EXLinearGradient (from `../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios`)
  - EXLocalAuthentication (from `../node_modules/expo-local-authentication/ios`)
  - EXLocalization (from `../node_modules/expo-localization/ios`)
  - EXLocation (from `../node_modules/expo-location/ios`)
  - EXMailComposer (from `../node_modules/expo-mail-composer/ios`)
  - EXMediaLibrary (from `../node_modules/expo-media-library/ios`)
  - EXPermissions (from `../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios`)
  - ExpoKit/Core (from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.11.5`)
  - EXPrint (from `../node_modules/expo-print/ios`)
  - EXRandom (from `../node_modules/expo-random/ios`)
  - EXSecureStore (from `../node_modules/expo-secure-store/ios`)
  - EXSegment (from `../node_modules/expo-analytics-segment/ios`)
  - EXSensors (from `../node_modules/expo-sensors/ios`)
  - EXSharing (from `../node_modules/expo-sharing/ios`)
  - EXSMS (from `../node_modules/expo-sms/ios`)
  - EXSpeech (from `../node_modules/expo-speech/ios`)
  - EXSQLite (from `../node_modules/expo-sqlite/ios`)
  - EXTaskManager (from `../node_modules/expo-task-manager/ios`)
  - EXWebBrowser (from `../node_modules/expo-web-browser/ios`)
  - Firebase/Auth (~> 6.3.0)
  - Firebase/Firestore (~> 6.3.0)
  - Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)
  - glog (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`)
  - React/ART (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/CxxBridge (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/DevSupport (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTCameraRoll (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTGeolocation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTImage (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTNetwork (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTText (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - UMBarCodeScannerInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios`)
  - UMCameraInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios`)
  - UMConstantsInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios`)
  - "UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`)"
  - UMFaceDetectorInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios`)
  - UMFileSystemInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios`)
  - UMFontInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios`)
  - UMImageLoaderInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios`)
  - UMPermissionsInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios`)
  - "UMReactNativeAdapter (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios`)"
  - UMSensorsInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios`)
  - UMTaskManagerInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios`)
  - yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git:
    - Amplitude-iOS
    - Analytics
    - AppAuth
    - Bolts
    - boost-for-react-native
    - BoringSSL-GRPC
    - Branch
    - CocoaLumberjack
    - Crashlytics
    - Fabric
    - FBAudienceNetwork
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseAuthInterop
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseFirestore
    - Google-Maps-iOS-Utils
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities
    - GoogleMaps
    - GoogleMobileVision
    - GoogleNetworkingUtilities
    - GoogleSignIn
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities
    - GoogleToolboxForMac
    - GoogleUtilities
    - "gRPC-C++"
    - gRPC-Core
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - JKBigInteger2
    - leveldb-library
    - lottie-ios
    - nanopb
    - Protobuf

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  DoubleConversion:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  EXAdsAdMob:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-ads-admob/ios"
  EXAdsFacebook:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-ads-facebook/ios"
  EXAmplitude:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-analytics-amplitude/ios"
  EXAppAuth:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-app-auth/ios"
  EXAppLoaderProvider:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-app-loader-provider/ios"
  EXAV:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-av/ios"
  EXBackgroundFetch:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-background-fetch/ios"
  EXBarCodeScanner:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner/ios"
  EXBlur:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-blur/ios"
  EXBrightness:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-brightness/ios"
  EXCalendar:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-calendar/ios"
  EXCamera:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-camera/ios"
  EXConstants:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-constants/ios"
  EXContacts:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-contacts/ios"
  EXCrypto:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-crypto/ios"
  EXDocumentPicker:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-document-picker/ios"
  EXFacebook:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-facebook/ios"
  EXFaceDetector:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-face-detector/ios"
  EXFileSystem:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios"
  EXFont:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-font/ios"
  EXGL:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-gl/ios"
  EXGL-CPP:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-gl-cpp/cpp"
  EXGoogleSignIn:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-google-sign-in/ios"
  EXHaptics:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-haptics/ios"
  EXImageManipulator:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-image-manipulator/ios"
  EXImagePicker:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-image-picker/ios"
  EXKeepAwake:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios"
  EXLinearGradient:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios"
  EXLocalAuthentication:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-local-authentication/ios"
  EXLocalization:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-localization/ios"
  EXLocation:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-location/ios"
  EXMailComposer:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-mail-composer/ios"
  EXMediaLibrary:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-media-library/ios"
  EXPermissions:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios"
  ExpoKit:
    :git: http://github.com/expo/expo.git
    :tag: ios/2.11.5
  EXPrint:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-print/ios"
  EXRandom:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-random/ios"
  EXSecureStore:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-secure-store/ios"
  EXSegment:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-analytics-segment/ios"
  EXSensors:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-sensors/ios"
  EXSharing:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-sharing/ios"
  EXSMS:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-sms/ios"
  EXSpeech:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-speech/ios"
  EXSQLite:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-sqlite/ios"
  EXTaskManager:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-task-manager/ios"
  EXWebBrowser:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/expo-web-browser/ios"
  Folly:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
  glog:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  React:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native"
  UMBarCodeScannerInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios"
  UMCameraInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios"
  UMConstantsInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios"
  UMCore:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios"
  UMFaceDetectorInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios"
  UMFileSystemInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios"
  UMFontInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios"
  UMImageLoaderInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios"
  UMPermissionsInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios"
  UMReactNativeAdapter:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios"
  UMSensorsInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios"
  UMTaskManagerInterface:
    :path: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: "../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios"
  yoga:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

CHECKOUT OPTIONS:
  ExpoKit:
    :git: http://github.com/expo/expo.git
    :tag: ios/2.11.5

COCOAPODS: 1.8.4
```

At this point, I have no idea what's going wrong so any help would be appreciated

Comment: trying cleaning the project and removing DerivedData

Comment: Might be related to using an old version of Firebase - 6.3.0 versus the current 6.14.0